# pass multiple arguments in sector with NSthread in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I want to pass two arguments to method with NSThread. I tried using [this third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327617/calling-selector-with-two-arguments-on-nsthread-issue). But unfortunatlly that code was not working well because `andKeys:`
method is not available.

```
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(DownloadCheckServerPath:DirectoryName:) toTarget:self withObject:"How to pass two objects"];
```

So how should I called `-(void)DownloadCheckServerPath:(NSString *)serverPath DirectoryName:(NSString *)directoryName` this method in Sector through NSThread. ?

Comment: [this question has already been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd/8439084#8439084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass multiple arguments to a method which is invoked by this message send. Workaround: use collections. One argument is more than enough.

```
- (void)reallyCallMethod:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    [self downloadCheckServerPath:dict[@"path"] directoryName:dict[@"dir"]];
}

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(reallyCallMethod:)
                         toTarget:self
                       withObject:@{ @"path" : @"/foo/bar", @"dir" : @"baz" }];
```

Also: **don't begin selector names with capital letters.** That's for classes only (and it's *really ugly,* isn't it?)

Comment: yesh! Now function is working fine. Thankz for the answer. Still I am beginner of the objective c. that's y. :)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I have typically created an NSDictionary and passed that. In the function I read the dictionary and get all the elements that I need.